# Converting byte array to String and String to byte array in Java

Tags: java

I converted byte array `bytes` to String. But when calculating the bytes in the string, I am not getting correct answer.  The size of `bytes` is 125, but I'm getting 129.
The code is given below:

```
    String s2= null;
    try {

        System.out.println(bytes.length);           //This gives 125 as answer
        s2 = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(s2.getBytes("UTF-8").length); //But this gives 129 instead of 125
   } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What is wrong with above code?

**EDIT:** Based on the answers given below, `bytes` is encoded in the wrong format. If initialization of `bytes` done as shown below, then how to convert `bytes` to string without 
losing(or gaining) any extra data?

```
byte[] bytes=new byte[125];
    for (int i = 0; i < 125; i++) {       
        bytes[bytes.length - i / 8 - 1] |= 1 << (i % 8);
     }
```

**Update:** If I remove the shift operation in above code it is giving correct output. What is the problem with shifting?

Comment: he said 129 in his code

Comment: That is probably due to an encoding error in the original `bytes`. Can you give us the original byte array?

Comment: I get 125 when I run your code with `byte[] bytes = new byte[125];`

Comment: I'm using version `1.7.0_45-b18`

Comment: What is your input String, s2?

Comment: @stoooops, s2 is new String initialized with `bytes`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that `s2 = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");` added additional bytes because the original string was not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigating my code, I found that `bytes` array contains negative values. If a `byte array` contains negative values, using `UTF-8` encoding will add extra characters in the resulting string. That's why when I converted this string back to `byte array` extra characters are introduced thus increasing the `byte array` length.

Using encoding method `ISO-8859-1` solved my problem.

Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should *work*, provided the data in `bytes` is actually UTF-8 encoded.

It will not work, it the data in `bytes` is anything else (except maybe an UTF-8-compatible encoding such as ASCII).

That is because not every possible sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 sequence. And when one of the invalid sequences is encountered, then it will be replaced with the Unicode replacement character. Converting that back to bytes will *not* reproduce the original bytes.

You seem to have a deeper issue here: what is `bytes` and why do you want to convert it to a  `String` in the first place?

Comment: Thank you. May be `bytes` was not  "UTF-8" encoded. Is there any way to know it's encoding?

Comment: @Kiran: there's no sure way without knowing where it comes from. You can guess, but the best way is to ask whoever/whatever provided it to you. Where did they come from?

Comment: `bytes` are initialized with random integers less than 100. Can you tell me what to do in this case?

Comment: I edited my question now. It contains initialization of `bytes`.  Can you tell me what is the correct way to convert this `bytes ` to Stirng?

Comment: @Kiran: well, what do you expect the String to contain? The numbers in decimal form? "random integers less than 100" will not produce a usable String when interpreting them using any common encoding (it will some letters and digits, but many control characters as well).

Comment: Actually I don't want to use this string. I want to convert it back to bytes. So, `UTF-8` will not be useful for doing so if bytes contains negative numbers. So, I used `ISO-8859-1` encoding.

Comment: @Kiran: NO! If you don't want the String, then don't try to store binary data in it! **Don't use a `String` at all!** They are not meant to store binary data, `byte[]` is perfectly adequate for that! If you *must* convert arbitrary binary data to a `String` representation, then use something like Base64 (or a simple hex representation for short data).